# How do I get an F1 visa when I already have a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I have a 10-year B1/B2 visa valid from November 2015. I visited the US for a week in February 2016 to tour New York. In May 2017, I was admitted to a university, got the I-20 form and paid the Sevis fee. How do I apply for the F1 visa? I filled out the DS-160 form but it didn't allow me to pay the application fee, as it shows that I already have a B1/B2 visa.

Comment: You are mistaken, perhaps you didn't fill the forms correctly. You are allowed to apply for an F1 while holding a b1/b2 which the consular officer may choose to cancel at the interview after issuing you the F1.

Comment: i filled the form ds-160 correctly and the application was successfully submitted.only while paying the application fee,i encountered the problem

Comment: The problem occured in cgifederal.secure.force.com. we are not ale to delete my husband's information. We are required to pay only for my son's f1 visa.

Comment: Please update your question and clarify: first you say that you have a B1/B2 visa, that you applied for an F1... now you say that the F-1 is for your son, that you husband's information need to be deleted. Did you upload your previous DS-160 and use it to create a new application? That may be the issue.